# A stop job is running for Raise network interfaces (/1min 31s)

Tags: boot, networking, shutdown

When I am trying to shutdown my pc running ubuntu 16.04.5 it will hang on this line:

```
A stop job is running for Raise network interfaces (1s/1min 31s)
```

This is my /etc/network/interfaces file:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug enp0s31f6
iface enp0s31f6 inet dhcp
```

I added allow-hotplug because I was getting another error at **booting**

```
A start job is running for Raise network interfaces (1s/5min 2s)
```

Can someone help me how can I fix this ?

Thank you for any help.